# Is there a way to enqueue a message to SQS queue without using the AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Suppose I have the SQS url, access and secrets keys for my AWS account. Is there a way to put a message in this queue without using the AWS SDK? Let's say using curl command.

Comment: I'm really curious about your use case. Why is this something you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [AWS CLI tool](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/). Or you could go through the process of [creating a Signature V4 signed request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) and submitting it with curl (I'd recommend writing code that uses the AWS SDK before going that route).

Comment: Upvote. You can also log in to your account and manually post a message via AWS console, if it is a one-time thing.